# Making Matplotlib and GTK3 work on python3 windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, gtk3, cairo

I'm trying to make GTK3 and Python3 work under windows to my project.

I have an continuum anaconda setup with a 32-bit python 3.4 and Matplotib via
conda install matplotlib.

I've installed PyGobject(https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/) and installed GTK+ / Glade via the installer.

The basic exemple from the GTK3 tutorial works well (empty screen)

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I want now to embed matplotlib in gtk, I got the example from matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk3.html)

I saw then that I needed cairocffi because some incompabilities. (PyCairo has no support for a matplotlib function)

I got the windows binaries for cffi from Gohlke

And finnaly did a

```
pip install cairocffi
```

And now I just get a python.exe stopped working.

Tried with GTK3agg and GTK3Cairo backends and I have the same result

Looking around I found that maybe the cairo version is outdated for the functions used by matplotlib, but I dont know how to proceed.

Cairocffi works if I try running something else.

**More information** (from the comment below):

I still got an unhandled win32 error. I managed to open the error and it says:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x08CF6D58 (libcairo-2.dll) in python.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000A8.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

It just crashes...

Answer (score 0):

I've had my share of problems using `matplotlib` in `Python3 + Gtk3`. I found [this cookbook page](http://gtk3-matplotlib-cookbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hello-plot.html#embedding-matplotlib) with working examples. Try to run the examples in the cookbook - particularly the simplest one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy import arange, pi, random, linspace
import matplotlib.cm as cm
#Possibly this rendering backend is broken currently
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3agg import FigureCanvasGTK3Agg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3cairo import FigureCanvasGTK3Cairo as FigureCanvas

myfirstwindow = Gtk.Window()
myfirstwindow.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
myfirstwindow.set_default_size(400, 400)

fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

N = 20
theta = linspace(0.0, 2 * pi, N, endpoint=False)
radii = 10 * random.rand(N)
width = pi / 4 * random.rand(N)

bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)

for r, bar in zip(radii, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(cm.jet(r / 10.))
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)

ax.plot()

sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
myfirstwindow.add(sw) 

canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
canvas.set_size_request(400,400)
sw.add_with_viewport(canvas)

myfirstwindow.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Also, not that you need a fairly recent version of `matplotlib` to make things work on `Python3`.

If you still have problems, please show us the complete error message.

Note: I tested this on Linux (don't have Windows), but, from you description of problems, the issue is (was) a common one.

Comment: Hello, I found this site too and tried it. I still got an unhandled win32 error. I managed to open the error and it says:

Unhandled exception at 0x08CF6D58 (libcairo-2.dll) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000A8.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

It just crashes...

Comment: Can't really help you - As I understand it, the Gtk3Agg backend isn't functional at the moment, so you have no choice but to use the Gtk3Cairo one. The problem behind all this is the change to Introspection to link Python3 to Gtk3. Matplotlib was not using Introspection originally, and has 'just' been updated to use it. But this means that you problem may be originating in many different places. You might consider trying your program in Python2. There's not *that* much difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Windows since years. The documentation of matplotlib 2.0.0 realease states that [Gtk3 backend is not supported on Windows](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/users/installing.html). Recently, I had an issue running the Gtk3Agg backend under Linux (Ubuntu). In both cases, it is always related to Cairo.

Thus, I wrote my own implementation of this backend, you can find it [here](https://gitlab.com/Charbonnier/matplotlib_gtk3_agg_backend). import the FigureCanvasGtk3Agg from my module and use it the same way as the official one. It lacks some features, but, if you just want to display a plot, it'll do the job.

You can try the module by running it, it should display a simple colorful graph in a window. I tried it under both Linux and Windows and had no issue.

**How does it works:**

The trick is to avoid importing Cairo in Python3 as it usually doesn't work (to my experience). It is done by using a `GdkPixbuf`.

Then `Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf` does the rest of the job along with calling two methods of the cairo context provided by Gtk in the 'draw-event' callback. Cairo is never imported in the module.